# JPA: NamedQuery of name: <query> not found

Tags: jpa, entity, toplink, toplink-essentials

I'm using Netbeans 6.9.1 and TopLink Essentials for the JPA.
I had followed the necessary steps for JPA connection.

Yet when I execute a named query in a particular entity.
This exception always return to me

```
NamedQuery of name: [the query name] not found.
```

How is this possible and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Could you show the relevant snippets of code? e.g. named query definition and entity definition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had solved the problem.
I can't be sure but overwriting the persistence.xml seemed to be a solution

Comment: I am getting the same exception in my Desktop application. Overwriting the persistence.xml is not working in mine. I using toplink.

Comment: @BheshGurung Make sure that the entity where the query is named is included in the persistence.xml.  This is especially crucial if exclude-unlisted-classes has been set to true.

Comment: It works! After create the new persistence.xml you have to restart the server.